# Does the asymptotic normality hold for panel structured data?

Tags: regression, panel-data, normality-assumption

In regression, the asymptotic normality requires, other than the central limit theorem, observations are independent, and panel data clearly violates this assumption as observations are at least correlated within an observation unit (e.g., family, firm, etc.). Does it means we can't use the asymptotic normality for panel data? Then how can we make inferences from panel data when errors are not normally distributed? What are the remedies for this problem?

I presume that there must be something that I missed, so please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite correct to say that asymptotic normality requires independence *in addition* to the central limit theorem.  Rather, independence of observations in a regression model is a condition that allows one to apply the simplest version of the central limit theorem (Lindberg-Levy CLT).

The so-called 'central limit theorem' is actually a generic reference to a fairly large group of theorems which yield asymptotic normality under different input assumptions.  Generally speaking, those assumptions are designed to ensure that no individual data point counts for a positive proportion of the mean as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  This generally requires assumptions that: (a) the underlying distribution of the data is not too heavy-tailed; and (b) the data are either independent, or at least not too strongly correlated (e.g., variables that are far apart are nearly independent).

There are various versions of the CLT that deal with mean statistics constructed from correlated observations.  There are some fairly general versions that deal with 'mixing processes' where the data are correlated, and these might be helpful.  There are also some more specific versions that are constructed for specific models.  For example, if your panel data is modelled as an AR(1) process (i.e., each response variable is regressed against the previous response, as well as the explanatory variables), then you could appeal to a version of the CLT that applies to this kind of process.  Alternatively, if your panel data is a linear mixed-model using random effects, you could appeal to a version of the CLT that deals with that kind of process.

As a general rule, most models for panel data will satisfy the requirements of a CLT for the resulting estimators.  Most models involve weak enough correlation structures that the parameter estimators are indeed asymptotically normal.  However, there will be some models where it doesn't hold.  In order to know whether or not asymptotic normality of your estimators will hold, you will need to formulate your specific model, and then check if there is a version of the CLT that applies to that type of model.  It may be helpful for you to familiarise yourself with CLTs for correlated random variables or mixing processes.  As a start, you can find a worked example of a CLT for an AR(1) model [here](http://www.econ.uzh.ch/static/wp_iew/iewwp480.pdf).

Comment: Thanks so much for your insightful answer! The manuscript you suggested was also very helpful. Inhave a clarification question. Let’s say I have run a regression with one million data points and the residuals are still non-normal. What does it imply? I know the clt does not provide about specific sample sizes to secure, but one million could be considered fairly large.

Comment: The CLT does not require normality of the underlying distribution, so that is not a problem.  Usually the only assumption the CLT requires about the underlying distribution is that it must have finite variance.  This encompasses a wide class of non-normal distributions (but not all of them).  In a regression with non-normal error distribution, I'd have a look at the distribution of the residuals, and especially at its 'tail plot'.  So long as the points in the tail plot do not show heavy-tails, you are okay.

Comment: Also, for the purposes of the CLT, one million observations is **massive**.  Even if you start with an underlying distribution that is very far from normality, you will start to see convergence to the normal very rapidly.  About 6-10 observations you will already see it start to become hump-shaped, and with 30-50 observations it will be very difficult to distinguish from the normal with the naked eye.  By the time you have even 100 observations, you will not be able to distinguish the distribution from a normal on a density plot unless you zoom in.